# Trouble with embedded repeaters with the relating the inner repeater to the outer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am struggling to set the FolderID integer to the FolderID property on the FolderList collection. FolderList is bound to the outer repeater. Most examples I have seen use DataTables and not custom collections. I have looked around and really can't find anything to help me.

```
'--------------------------------------------------------
'Protected Sub Page_Load()
'--------------------------------------------------------
'.
'.
'.
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    '----------------------------------------------------
    'Output
    '----------------------------------------------------
    '.
    '.
    '.
    With Folders

        '------------------------------------------------
        'Data
        '------------------------------------------------
        '.
        '.
        '.
        .DataSource = New FolderList(1)

        '------------------------------------------------
        'Bind
        '------------------------------------------------
        '.
        '.
        '.
        .DataBind()

    End With

End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------
'Protected Sub Folders_ItemDataBound()
'--------------------------------------------------------
'.
'.
'.
Private Sub Folders_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Folders.ItemDataBound

    '----------------------------------------------------
    'Declarations
    '----------------------------------------------------
    '.
    '.
    '.
    Dim Item As Repeater = e.Item.FindControl("Files")

    '----------------------------------------------------
    'Output
    '----------------------------------------------------
    '.
    '.
    '.
    With Item

        Dim FolderID As Int32 = 1

        '------------------------------------------------
        'Data
        '------------------------------------------------
        '.
        '.
        '.
        .DataSource = New PageList(FolderID)

        '------------------------------------------------
        'Bind
        '------------------------------------------------
        '.
        '.
        '.
        .DataBind()

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is an interesting comment method.

Comment: Are you asking how to set FolderID to the e.Item value?

Comment: Tried things like: Dim FolderID As Int32 = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(e.Item, "FolderID") with no luck

Comment: Yes - to the property called FolderID.

Comment: I think I just found it.  Dim FolderID As Int32 = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(e.Item.DataItem, "FolderID")

Answer (score 1):

Dim FolderID As Int32 = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(e.Item.DataItem, "FolderID")